# Shading issues when exporting

Tags: shaders, export, geometry

My model looks fine in Blender and there are no problems, however when I export it (to the Substance Painter for instance) there are artifacts all over the surface.

[image]

[image]

It could be the issue with substance, I thought about that, but something tells me that it's either normals in Blender or the export itself.
The thing is that I just recently did another project and everything was fine, both in Blender and in Substance.

Btw I don't know whether it matters but I have started doing thin one on Blender 2.82 and later accidentally opened this file in Blender 3.6 (My laptop is slow that's why I prefer using the older one). Then I just kept doing it in 3.6.

At first I thought it happened due to the triangulation but when I reversed it, the issues were still there. I've tried reapplying *Weighted Normals*, *Autosmooth* and all that and I really don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Hello could you please share your object or at least the part with the bad shading?

Comment: I'm not sure about SP support of split normals, and the custom normals are definitely the problem here.  Can you live with a normal map instead of custom normals?  If so, you can bake object space normals and use them on a mesh without custom normals; you can bake those to tangent space normals afterwards from the obj space normals if you'd prefer, although on this mesh, obj space normals should be fine.